# display list data in a div as announcement with auto horizontal scrolling

Tags: list, office-365

I have created a list for announcement in my **Office 365**, and now I have fetch list data and display on home page in a div as latest announcement?

How I can implement this, like a flash news on home page.

Comment: What code have you tried sofar? We can help you fix programming errors, but we can not do your job.

Comment: i worked in weparts , but o365 not fetches data in from the list

Comment: am new to O365,webparts only works on SSOM.  can  you pls suggest  logic to display list data in a div . i mean in which way i can implement.

Answer (score 0):

You have to develop Snadbox soltution with CSOM to deploy on Office 365.

I can't give exact logic for your requirement. But get logic from following link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/399156/SharePoint-Client-Object-Model-Introduction